# simplify jquery Sticky menu scroll to function

Tags: jquery, navigation, jquery-animate, scrollto, sticky

I am having a horizontal navigation on my one page website, which is becoming a sticky nav at a certain waypoint. Now I created a working scroll to navigation that looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button0").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#ziel_top").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
    $("#button1").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#ziel_1").offset().top-100
        }, 2000);
    });
    $("#button2").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#ziel_2").offset().top-100
        }, 2000);
    });
    $("#button3").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#ziel_3").offset().top-100
        }, 2000);
    });
    $("#button4").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#ziel_4").offset().top-100
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Now my question to you, would there be a method to simplify this function? Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that all the `#button`s are actually buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[id^=button]").click(function() {
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        id=id.substr(id.length-1);
        if(id==0){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#ziel_top").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
        else{
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#ziel_"+id).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the button is actually just an "a-tag"
`<li><a id="button0" href="#!">Start</a></li>`

Comment: would you please accept the answer if it in fact solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
for (var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   $("#button" + i).click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#ziel_" + i).offset().top-100
      }, 2000);
    });
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty neat. Thank you! would that also work automatically if I added morethan 5 links/buttons?

Comment: Absolutely. And for any number.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a shameless plug but you could use [jquery.localScroll](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll).
You'll only need a single line of js and then you setup the navigation on the HTML (which will work even if JS is disabled).